# CSS position problem for horizontal menu on Safari/Chrome of text

Tags: css, webkit, positioning, css-float

I have searched high and low for an answer to this - there are a few things i've tried such as removing charset UTF 8, adding clear both, ensuring all container widths are set, and so on.

Can any of you spot the problem though in the CSS and HTML below as to why when I converted this custom theme from html into Wordpress it suddenly decided that it would render the menu differently in webkit browsers? It still works fine on Firefox.

Any help would be very much appreciated so i can get some sleep again!

This is for http://silvermoths.com

This is the HTML for the header

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">

<div id="social">
<ul>
<li id="spotify"><a href="http://open.spotify.com/artist/4Adcr34XrVCTVJbfvJGBxQ"></a>
<li id="myspace"><a href="http://myspace.com/silvermoths"></a>
<li id="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/silvermoths"></a>
<li id="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/silvermoths"></a>
</ul>

<form id="email" action='http://madmimi.com/signups/subscribe/29549' method='post'>

   <label for='signup_email'>Enter Email:</label> 
<input id='signup_email' class="text" name='signup[email]' type='text' /><br />

<input name='commit' class='button' type='submit' value='Signup now to keep informed' />


</form>

</div><!--end of social-->

<div id="banner">
<a href="http://silvermoths.com"><img src="<?php echo(get_bloginfo('template_directory')); ?>/images/logo.png" width="468" height="189" alt="Silvermoths" class="logo" />
<h1>Silvermoths</h1>

</div><!--end of banner-->


<div id="nav">
<ul>
<?php wp_page_menu('show_home=1'); ?>
</ul>
</div><!--end of navigation-->


</div><!--end of header-->
```

This is the CSS:

```
    /*
Theme Name: Silvermoths 
Theme URI: http://silvermoths.com
Description: Custome theme for Silvemroths  
Author: Rylan Holey
Version: 1.0 
Tags: orange, social buttons, two coloumn

License:
License URI:

General comments (optional).
*/

html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr {margin:0; padding:0;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th {font-size:1em; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;}
ul,ol {list-style:none;}
fieldset,img,hr {border:none;}
caption,th {text-align:left;}
table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
td {vertical-align:top;}





/* CSS Document */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVuSerifBook';
    src: url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.svg#webfontO0VgJAHF') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'TendernessRegular';
    src: url('Tenderness-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Tenderness-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('Tenderness-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Tenderness-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Tenderness-webfont.svg#webfontaYPTm82W') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:url('images/body_bg.jpg');
    background-color:#f05323;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}
.wp-caption {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px; /* optional rounded corners for browsers that support it */
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
.wp-caption img {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px 5px;
}

#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left:auto;   

    border-bottom: #e87529 solid 10px;
    }

#header {
    width:960px;
    height:350px !important;

}   



#banner{

    height: 189px;
    width: 468px;
}

#banner img{
    border-style: none;

}

#banner h1{
    float:left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}



#banner .logo {
    float:left;
    width:468px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}

#description h2{
    text-indent: -9999px;  
}

#social{ 
    clear:both;
    width:320px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px
}

#social li, #social a {
    height:64px;
    display:block;

}


#social ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}

#social  li {   
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:16px;
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    display:block;

    }

#social a:link, #social a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: none;
}


    #twitter {left:0px;width:64px;}
    #twitter {background:url('images/twitter_sprite.png') 0 0;}
    #twitter a:hover{background: url('images/twitter_sprite.png') 0 -65px;}
    #twitter a:active{background: url('images/twitter_sprite.png') 0 -130px;}

    #facebook {left:0px;width:64px;}
    #facebook {background:url('images/facebook_sprite.png') 0 0;}
    #facebook a:hover{background: url('images/facebook_sprite.png') 0 -65px;}
    #facebook a:active{background: url('images/facebook_sprite.png') 0 -130px;}


    #spotify {left:0px;width:64px;}
    #spotify {background:url('images/spotify_sprite.png') 0 0;}
    #spotify a:hover{background: url('images/spotify_sprite.png') 0 -65px;}
    #spotify a:active{background: url('images/spotify_sprite.png') 0 -130px;}

    #myspace {left:0px;width:64px;}
    #myspace {background:url('images/myspace_sprite.png') 0 0;}
    #myspace a:hover{background: url('images/myspace_sprite.png') 0 -65px;}
    #myspace a:active{background: url('images/myspace_sprite.png') 0 -130px;}



#social img
{  border-style: none;
}

form#email
{
    clear:both;
    width:300px;
    height:102px;
    float:right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 29px;
    margin-bottom: 29px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:24px 0 0 0;
    background-image: url(images/content_bg.png);
    font-family:'TendernessRegular', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:22px;


    }

label
    {

    color:#FFF;


}



#email .button {
    margin-top:15px;
    width:238px;
    height:37px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-family:Arial, Sans serif;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    background: url('images/signup_button.png') 0 0;
    }

#email .button:hover {
    margin-top:15px;
    width:238px;
    height:37px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-family:Arial, Sans serif;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    background: url('images/signup_button.png') 0 -38px;
    }

#email .button:active {
    margin-top:15px;
    width:238px;
    height:37px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-family:Arial, Sans serif;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    background: url('images/signup_button.png') 0 -77px;
    }

#email .text {
    height:30px;

}


#nav {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    font-family:'TendernessRegular', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #e5e8e6;
    font-size:30px;
    height:70px;
    width:960px;    
    text-align:left;
    background-image: url('images/content_bg.png');
    z-index:0;

}

#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:17px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav  li {  
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:0;
    height:70px;
    z-index:100;



    }

#nav a:link, #nav  a:visited {
    padding: 15px 0.5em 15.5px 0.5em;
    color: #e5e8e6;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color:#FFF;

}
#nav a:active {
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}


#sidebar {

    float:right;
    width:260px;
    margin:15px 10px 15px 10px ;
    padding:20px;
    background-image: url('images/content_bg.png');
    height: 100%;

}

#single img {
    border:none;
    background:none;
}

#content {

    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:580px;
    margin:15px 10px 15px 10px;
    padding:20px;
    background-image: url('images/content_bg.png');

}

#content .post-image img {
    float:left;

    margin:15px 15px 15px 10px;

    border-top: 1px solid #555;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #3c3a3a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #242424;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #242424;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #242424;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;

}






#placeholder {

    height:350px;
    border: 1px solid  #bb3e26;
    margin-top:10px;
    background: #FFE7CF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;

}

#placeholder .meta {

    margin: 150px 10px 0 10px;
    text-align:left;
}   

#placeholder h3 {

    font-family:'TendernessRegular', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #bb3e26;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-style: italic;

}

#text {

    clear:both;

}


#footer h1, #sidebar h1, #content h1 {
    font-family:'TendernessRegular', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:50px;
    margin-top:0.3em;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-weight:bold;



}

#sidebar h2, #content h2 {
    font-family:'TendernessRegular', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-weight:bold;

}

#sidebar h3, #content h3 {
    font-family:'TendernessRegular', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:22px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-weight:bold;

}

#sidebar h1+p, #sidebar h2+p, #content h1+p, #content h2+p, #placeholder h3+p  {
    margin-top:0;
}

#sidebar p, #content p {
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:14px;

}


#content a:link, #content a:visited {

    color: #bb3e26;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#content a:hover {
    color:#5e1f12;
}



#post {
    padding-top:0.5em;
    border-bottom:2px solid #5e1f12;
    height:125px;
}

#post .thumb {

    float:right;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#5e1f12 ;
    border-width:2px;
    margin:5px 10px 2px 5px;
}

#content a:link, #content a:visited {
    color: #1D4896;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#content a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#3c3a3a;
}

#content .post {
border-style: none;

}

#sidebar ul {
    list-style:none
}


#searchform input {
    margin-left:45px

}



#footer {

    clear:both;
    width:920px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#f05323;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding:20px;
}

#footer .copyright {

    float:right;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though the problem is being caused by a phantom empty link within the `<div class="menu">` just above the `<ul>`. See attached image.

[image]

It's weird because it doesn't seem to be in the source code which leads me to think it's being generated by wordpress?

If you use Chrome's developer plugin you can *inspect the element* to view where the link is being generated.